# How to reset to initial state when using A-Frame `state` component?

Tags: javascript, aframe

If I follow instructions [here](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/state#defining-state) and I have a game that changes the state over time, how do I reset the state?

Here's my attempt at pseudo code that does not work:

```
AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.state.state.game = AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.state.initialState.game;
```

Or perhaps it is not possible to fetch initial settings from the component, and instead I should create a global constant in my project like `initialStateMine` that is used by the state component for initialization and also another function to reset the state?

Comment: It will not recall the initial stat, you need to do your own and rather than in a global variable, try to use prototype (reset() method) and inject the values in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, keep an initial state in a variable. Then if you want to replace `Object.assign(state, initialState)`;

Comment: Thanks, this helped me come up with the following line inside of a state handler:
`Object.assign(state.game, initialState.game);`